# Can't get vitamio to show subtitle

Tags: android-videoview, vitamio

I'm using vitamio lib to make a video player. However, I can not find a way out to show embed subtitle. I've searched thoroughly on the Internet but there is no sample code. Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;

    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mVideoView
            .setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mVideoView.setSubShown(true);
            mVideoView.setSubPath(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/pi.srt");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vitamio 4.0 preview version](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/v4)

Comment: I try, and aways get this error: `THIS SUBTITLE NO DECODER 0x53526970` and `NO SUBTITLE DATA FOUND -1` Crossle